# Suitable Java data structure for parsing large data file

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap

I have a rather large text file (~4m lines) I'd like to parse and I'm looking for advice about a suitable data structure in which to store the data. The file contains lines like the following:

```
Date        Time    Value
2011-11-30  09:00   10
2011-11-30  09:15   5
2011-12-01  12:42   14
2011-12-01  19:58   19
2011-12-01  02:03   12
```

I want to group the lines by date so my initial thought was to use a `TreeMap<String, List<String>>` to map the date to the rest of the line but is a `TreeMap` of `List`s a ridiculous thing to do? I suppose I could replace the String key with a date object (to eliminate so many string comparisons) but it's the `List` as a value that I'm worried might be unsuitable.

I'm using a `TreeMap` because I want to iterate the keys in date order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is a TreeMap of Lists a ridiculous thing to do?

Conceptually not, but it is going to be very memory-inefficient (both because of the `Map` and because of the `List`). You're looking at an overhead of 200% or more. Which may or may not be acceptable, depending on how much memory you have to waste.

For a more memory-efficient solution, create a class that has fields for every column (including a `Date`), put all those in a `List` and sort it (ideally using quicksort) when you're done reading.

Comment: To be fair, the memory overhead of the Map depends a bit on the distribution of the keys. If many keys are reused a number of times this might even save memory.

Comment: How is it memory-inefficient to use a `List` as the value?  If you create a separate class to use as the value, and then store a `List` inside of that class, you're still creating the same number of `Lists`.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using a `List` as the value for a `Map`.  All of those `<>` look ugly, but it's perfectly fine to put a generics class inside of a generics class.

Instead of using a `String` as the key, it would probably be better to use `java.util.Date`  because the keys are dates.  This will allow the `TreeMap` to more accurately sort the dates.  If you store the dates as `Strings`, then the `TreeMap` may not properly sort the dates (they will be sorted as strings, not as "real" dates).

```
Map<Date, List<String>> map = new TreeMap<Date, List<String>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no objection against using Lists. Though in your case maybe a `List<Integer>` as values of the Map would be appropriate.

Comment: And how do you map the date-time to the elements of the list?

Comment: Through the `Map`, of course. Every element of the list under the same key had exactly that data/time.

Comment: Sorry, I only included a small sample of my data, there are more rows than just the date, time and value. Thanks for your suggestion though :)