# Java data structure for providing random <String><Float> pair based on a large data set at run-time

Tags: java, android, arrays, csv, data-structures

Is there a smart way to create a 'JSON-like' structure of String - Float pairs, 'key' not needed as data will be grabbed randomly - although an incremented key from 0-n might aid random retrieval of associated data. Due to the size of data set (10k pairs of values), I need this to be saved out to an external file type.

The reason is how my data will be compiled. To save someone entering data into an array manually the item will be excel based, saved out to CSV, parsed using a temporary java program to a file format (for example jJSON) which can be added to my project resources folder. I can then retrieve data from this set, without my application having to manually load a huge array into memory upon application creation. I can quite easily parse the CSV to 'fill-up' an array (or similar) at run-time - but I fear that on a mobile device, the memory overhead will be significant?

I have reviewed the answers to: [Suitable Java data structure for parsing large data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8324523/suitable-java-data-structure-for-parsing-large-data-file) and [Data structure options for efficiently storing sets of integer pairs on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426469/data-structure-options-for-efficiently-storing-sets-of-integer-pairs-on-disk) and have not been able to draw a definitive conclusion.

I have tried saving to a .JSON file, however not sure if I can request a random entry, plus this seems quite cumbersome for holding a simple structure. Is a treeMap or hashtable where I need to be focusing my search.

To provide some context to my query, my application will be running on android, and needs to reference a definition (approx 500 character String) and a conversion factor (an Float). I need to retrieve a random data entry. The user may only make 2 or 3 requests during a session - therefore see no point in loading a 10k element array into memory. QUERY: potentially modern day technology on android phones will easily munch through this type of query, and its perhaps only an issue if I am parsing millions of entries at run-time?

I am open to using SQLlite to hold my data if this will provide the functionality required. Please note that the data set must be derived from an easily exportable file format from excel (CSV, TXT etc).

Any advice you can give me would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possible design that requires a minimal memory footprint while providing fast access:

Start with a data file of comma-separated or tab-separated values so you have line breaks between your data pairs.

Keep an array of `long` values corresponding to the indexes of the lines in the data file.  When you know where the lines are, you can use `InputStream.skip()` to advance to the desired line.  This leverages the fact that `skip()` is typically quite a bit faster than `read` for `InputStream`s.

You would have some setup code that would run at initialization time to index the lines.

An enhancement would be to only index every *n*th line so that the array is smaller.  So if *n* is 100 and you're accessing line 1003, you take the 10th index to skip to line 1000, then read past two more lines to get to line 1003.  This allows you to tune the size of the array to use less memory.

I thought this was an interesting problem, so I put together some code to test my idea. It uses a sample 4MB CSV file that I downloaded from some big data website that has about 36K lines of data.  Most of the lines are longer than 100 chars.

Here's code snippet for the setup phase:

```
    long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    int lineCount = 0;
    try (InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.fl_insurance_sample)) {

        int index = 0;
        int charCount = 0;
        int cIn;
        while ((cIn = in.read()) != -1) {
            charCount++;

            char ch = (char) cIn;  // this was for debugging
            if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r') {
                lineCount++;
                if (lineCount % MULTIPLE == 0) {
                    index = lineCount / MULTIPLE;
                    if (index == mLines.length) {
                        mLines = Arrays.copyOf(mLines, mLines.length + 100);
                    }
                    mLines[index] = charCount;
                }
            }

        }

        mLines = Arrays.copyOf(mLines, index+1);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error reading raw resource", e);
    }

    long elapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;
```

I discovered my data file was actually separated by carriage returns rather than line feeds.  It must have been created on an Apple computer.  Hence the test for `'\r'` as well as `'\n'`.

Here's a snippet from the code to access the line:

```
                long start = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

                int ch;
                int line = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString().trim());
                if (line < 1 || line >= mLines.length ) {
                    mTextView.setText("invalid line: " + line + 1);
                }
                line--;
                int index = (line / MULTIPLE);
                in.skip(mLines[index]);
                int rem = line % MULTIPLE;
                while (rem > 0) {
                    ch = in.read();
                    if (ch == -1) {
                        return; // readLine will fail
                    } else if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r') {
                        rem--;
                    }
                }

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String text = reader.readLine();

                long elapsed = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;
```

My test program used an `EditText` so that I could input the line number.

So to give you some idea of performance, the first phase averaged around 1600ms to read through the entire file.  I used a `MULTIPLE` value of 10. Accessing the last record in the file averaged about 30ms.

To get down to 30ms access with only a 29312-byte memory footprint is pretty good, I think.

You can [see the sample project on GitHub](https://github.com/klarson2/DataRandomAccess).